# Infopath 2013 - Cant Use Data connection (Get data from sql )

Tags: infopath, data-connection

I build a simple list and customize the new form in infopath.
then I add new data connection and check receive data then select database and table (specially I add a table that have 10 row data)
So I use that fields in a repeating table so publish it to list.
After that when I open new form I see this error!
[image]

Then I check events and this is that event :

[image]
[image]

What is my problem?
**Thanks a lot for your time!**

Comment: So when I get data from SOAP Service see this error too!

Answer (score 0):

I solve this I must put the connection to the connection library and so Use that!

Comment: Please add more details to this answer!